# Parse string that may contain invalid daylight date

Tags: javascript

I need help to convert input string that looks something like `20160313023000` (invalid daylight saving date) to date in `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format using JavasScript.

I tried `new Date('20160313023000').getTime()` but the output that I get is `1969/12/31 19:00:00.000`

Comment: What have you tried? show a code example and we will correct you from there.

Comment: try moment.js http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I tried (new Date('20160313023000').getTime()); but the output that I get is    1969/12/31 19:00:00.000

Comment: @Pshemo - I must have set the wrong tag by accident.

Comment: @Nicolas - I would appreciate if had you put some effort in answering my question.

Comment: sorry I'm not a javascript expert, I let the experts answer

Answer (score 0):

That will parse your date:

```js
        function parseDate(date) {
            // format: yyyyMMddHHmmss
            var parsedDate = new Date(date.substr(0, 4),
                                      date.substr(4, 2),
                                      date.substr(6, 2),
                                      date.substr(8, 2),
                                      date.substr(10, 2),
                                      date.substr(12, 2));
            console.log(parsedDate);
        }

        parseDate("20160313023000");
```

But the "invalid daylight saving" actually depends on your locale.